# PrimeReact: how to obtain row index inside column body?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, primereact

I have a primereact `DataTable` with a column that contains a button like this:

```
<Column header="Actions" body={
    <div> 
        <Button icon="pi pi-pencil" className="p-button-rounded p-button-text" 
                onClick={(e) => {
                    //How do I obtain the row index here?
                }
            }/>
    </div>
}>                
</Column>
```

As you can see from the comment, I need to obtain the row index when the user clicks the button, because I want to perform an action on that specific row.

Is it possible? How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after tinkering further I found the solution:

```
<Column header="Actions" body={(data, props) => 
    <div> 
        <Button icon="pi pi-pencil" className="p-button-rounded p-button-text" 
                onClick={(e) => {
                    console.log("row idx: " + props.rowIndex);
                }
            }/>
    </div>
}>                
</Column>
```

Comment: How can I select the other data of that row?

Comment: @JohnPauloA.Geronimo: well, with the row index you can directly access the row of data by querying the same array of data that you passed to the `DataTable`'s  `value` property to populate it

Answer (score -1):

Other solution could be:

```
<Column className="bodyTemplate" body={(featureFlag: FeatureFlag) => RolesBodyTemplate(featureFlag?.roles)} />
```

Or

```
<Column className="bodyTemplate" body={userTypesBodyTemplate} />
```

Comment: How is that relevant to my question?